# GetConstructor.invoke error

Tags: c#, invoke, getconstructor

This is a study project. I have three database classes A,B,C. There is a factory class that receives thru its constructor which class's object to create. Each of the three classes[A,B,C] has a constructor with a parameter to supply the database connection object. This is the code I'm using in the factory class's createObject method:

```
Type classtyp = Type.GetType(className);

Type[] constrParam = new Type[1];
constrParam[0] = typeof(DBConnection);
ConstructorInfo constr = database.GetConstructor(constrParam);

return constr.Invoke(constrParam) as Database;
```

The last line above gives this error.

"***Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'.***"

How did the 'System.RuntimeType' get here? I'm trying to create an object of class A which has a constructor that takes a variable of type DBconnection.

Currently I'm passing to the factory class instructions to create an instance of class A only. This the code of class A:

```
public class SqlServerDB: Database
{
    string str = "";

    public SqlServerDB(DbConnection DBConn)
        : base(DBConn)
    {
        str = "SQLServer";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Invoke method takes the **object(s)** that you need to pass into the constructor. You're passing in the **type** DbConnection. What you should be passing in, is an instance of DbConnection.

To be a bit more clear, if you were directly creating one of these objects, you'd do something like this:

```
DbConnection connection = GetConnection(); //some method that gives you back a connection object
SqlServerDB db = new SqlServerDB(connection);
```

What you're doing though is the same as doing this:

```
Type type = typeof(DbConnection);
SqlServerDB db = new SqlServerDB(type); //This is obviously wrong.
```